# How to determine type of the value of an expression?

Tags: c++, types, expression, cout

1) When statements such as

```
cout << 3.0 + 3 ;
```

are made, how does one know whether the value passed to cout is an int or a float?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's neither. It's a double. `3.0` has type double, and `3` is promoted to double for the addition; the result of adding a double to a double is a double. That's independent of what's being done with the result.

There are a bunch of overloaded shift-left operators for ostreams, and there's one for an argument of type double on the right-hand side, so that's the one that's called:

```
template <class Elem, class Traits>
basic_ostream<Elem, Traits>& basic_ostream<Elem, Traits>::operator<<(double d);
```

For what it's worth, that's a member function, not a free function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. But what are the rules which determine what the type of the result will be ? (for a given pair of operands of different types)

Comment: @mahela007 - it gets a bit complicated, since there are so many types. But basically, integral types get promoted to the largest integral type in the expression, and floating-point types get promoted to the largest floating-point type. If the expression has both integral and floating-point types, the integral types get converted to floating-point types. This gets everything to the same type, and that's the type of the result. Now, that's just a sketch; it leaves out a lot of details that you can read about elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

It does this by taking advantage of overloading

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, int i) {
  // It's an int
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, float f) {
  // it's a float
}
```

The C++ compiler will pick the appropriate overload of the `<<` operator based on the input types.  If you pass a `float` it will pick the overload which has a `float` and the same for `int`

Answer (score 0):

Result of `3.0 + 3` operation is double thus cout will apply the << operator for double type.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Step into feature of debugger to determine this. In which cout method it will enter it is your answer